# AMD driver issues (Ubuntu 14.04 w/ KDE)

Tags: ati, xorg, kde, games, gpu-driver

As I am a user that moved from windows, I really enjoy PC gaming. So, when I moved over to Ubuntu, I realized that it really, really sucks. I think the main problem here is the AMD drivers, but I'm not very sure. I use Steam, and I play a lot of Counter Strike: Global Offensive. I was surprised to see that it ran like crap when I got it on Ubuntu. There was lots of screen tearing, I couldn't stay above 60 fps (vsync), and my card couldn't handle settings it was rated way above. If someone could lead me to an older driver, or anything, I would be extremely grateful. As some of you may know, Counter Strike is a very skill-demanding game, and I don't want Ubuntu (or AMD) getting in the way of this via framerate issues.

NOTE: Putting everything on low settings with native widescreen gives same results, minus filters and anti-aliasing, as those seem to put the most load on the card.

My card is: AMD RADEON R9 270X
It's not that old of a card, but it is pretty dated. This is what most suggested to use for Linux.

Comment: Did you install the proprietary drivers, or just try out games right away? I can write up an answer if it's the latter.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Yeah, I installed them. They work better than default drivers though.

Comment: Oh, you know what? Try this: open up the KDE System Monitor (search for it) and sort by which process is using the most RAM. Tell me what comes up in the top three. This might lead to you moving to another desktop environment, such as GNOME, but it might fix your problem.

Comment: @Zacharee1 The main reason why I got KDE was because someone recommended it with the recent drivers. I'm reinstalling KDE right now, because I fried Ubuntu twice today getting drivers, and messing up KDE's installation. Wish me luck!

Comment: Kubuntu 14.04 has a memory leak issue with Xorg. After about 5 hours, Xorg will be using 3/4 of your RAM.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Okay, the top 3 ps are: firefox, plasma-desktop, ksysguard

Comment: Hmm. How did you end up installing the drivers?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I installed a package from the official AMD website. It's also available on the Ubuntu application store.

Comment: Uninstall the downloaded one and install `fglrx-updates` using the terminal or Software Center.